# Render Tube and resize, dynamically add text

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, drawing, system.drawing

What I am looking to do in my Windows Forms application (or even WPF). Is to dynamically render an image of a tube, or cylinder (with a 3d look or having some sort of depth for a better visual experience), setting the length and hieght and so on, (also need rulers and such to zoom in and out). But then allow the user to enter some text, which will then be placed on that tube or cylinder, for display purposes, able to scale the text size, to create a visual representation of what it would look like IRL.

Any ideas on where I can start, or some examples I can build off of? This vector type display is new to me, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article looked interesting.  I would imagine you could tweak it to do what you were after.

http://kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm

Also I googled "WPF 3D drawing".

If you have the choice WPF is better suited for graphics than WinForms out of the box.  Though a good programmer can make WinForms do similar.

Comment: I think there might be a way to incorporate a portion of WPF in a wondows forms application, I havent found that yet, but I am looking.

Comment: At the risk of being the guy stating "Why would you want to do that" here I go... Why would you want to?  If you have the choice of how to start this project, start it in one or the other and create as little dependencies as possible.  Technology blending is great and all, but you need to have good reasons to do it.  And typically down the road your going to notice it bites you in the hind quarters.  The arguments for WPF here were your drawing requirement. If it were me I would go with that for the rest of the project too (nothing against winforms)

Comment: Time is the big issue, I am not as familiar with WPF as I am with kust about all the other frameworks out there. This part of the project is going to be built within another larger project which is all in WinForms. If I knew how to convert all the winforms to WPF, then I guess that would be ok, just take me longer to get it done. The learning curve just to get this piece done is already troublesome. Hard to even find suitable samples of this, simple drawing, then dynamically wrapping text on the rounded surface. Still looking, if I can do it all from WPF I will. Maybe I need to buy a book.

Comment: Try this: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms